# explanation regarding output of a c code

Tags: c

I found this code somewhere on the web, and I am able to make out all 4 cases but the last one is putting me again and again in a perplexing situation regarding its execution.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int a1[] = {6, 7, 8, 18, 34, 67};
int a2[] = {23, 56, 28, 29};
int a3[] = {-12, 27, -31};
int *x[] = {a1, a2, a3};
void print(int *a[])
{
        printf("%d,", a[0][2]);
        printf("%d,", *a[2]);
        printf("%d,", *++a[0]);
        printf("%d,", *(++a)[0]);
        printf("%d\n", a[-1][+1]);
}
main( )
{
         print(x);
}
```

What I thought is the best method of visualizing such cases is:

```
 a[0][2])=a-->a[0]-->a[0][2](way of understanding)=>a1[2]=8
```

on execution it gives output as:

```
8,-12,7,23,8
```

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: I think the more important thing here is to not use the increment operator like this as it decreases the readability of the code. If this were code you wrote I would suggest that you reconsider how you have wrote this.

Comment: @shuttle87 I think this is a learning example, not real code.

Comment: `*(++a)` This changes `a` to point to the next element, which is a pointer equivalent to `a2`

Comment: @NeilKirk, sure but I still think that it's worth pointing this out in case future readers come across this question. I edited the comment I made.

Comment: @neil a[-1][+1] is the thing which is worrying me .-1 is getting a to evaluate a2 but what +1 should have printed 7 from a1.??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to change the names for clarity and then go line by line:

```
void print(int *b[])
{
    printf("%d,", b[0][2]);
    printf("%d,", *b[2]);
    printf("%d,", *++b[0]);
    printf("%d,", *(++b)[0]);
    printf("%d\n", b[-1][+1]);
}

printf("%d,", b[0][2]);
```

`b[0]` is `a1` then `a1[2]` is 8

```
printf("%d,", *b[2]);
```

`b[2]` is `a3` and `*a3` is the first element of `a3` which is -12

```
printf("%d,", *++b[0]);
```

`b[0]` is `a1` then we increment so we have `*++a1` which is equivalent to `a1[1]` which is 7

```
printf("%d,", *(++b)[0]);
```

Now in this case we have to do `(++b)` first which is equivalent to `++x` which is `a2`. now we have `*a2[0]` which is 23. The important thing though is that we just changed `b`, the pointer for `b` just got incremented and stored the new pointer in `b`.

```
printf("%d\n", b[-1][+1]);
```

We have to remember that `b` changed one line before so `b` here starts as if it was `b+1` passed in originally. This means we are starting the pointer one address further along than before: so this is like we had `(x+1)[-1][+1]` which is `x[-1+1][+1+1]` or `x[0][2]` which is `a1[2]` which is 8.

This works like this because the array here really is just one continuous block of memory. Note that if you did `int **x` this would be different.

Note that this is the correct result as you can see when you run the code here: http://ideone.com/0mFvXn

Essentially on the last line what happened can be demonstrated by this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int a1[] = {6, 7, 8, 18, 34, 67};
int a2[] = {23, 56, 28, 29};
int a3[] = {-12, 27, -31};
int *x[] = {a1, a2, a3};

int main(void)
{
    printf("%d, %d \n", x[0][0], x[1][1]);
    int** z = x;
    ++z;
    printf("%d, %d \n", z[0][0], z[1][1]);
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
6, 56 
23, 27
```

Last code snippet on ideone: http://ideone.com/cB5y75

Additional note, there's much better clearer ways to write this type of code than the example code in the question so please don't do anything like this in production code. The second code snippet in this answer is quite a bit more clear in my mind than the first.